# how system("sync"); will work internally in linux

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

i was working in multimedia applications, and i know system() is a library call and "sync" is a Linux command which invokes sync(2) system in direclty. i need to know what happens exactly, while system("sync"); get executed

Comment: Start with: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/fs/sync.c#L97

Comment: `i need to know what happens exactly` - It executes *tons of code*. Really, what do you expect to be an answer to your **broad** question? What is unclear in [man 8 sync](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sync)?